# "The speech he ____ was"?

Tags: exam-questions

> The speech he **gave** was highly informative.

1. Deliver
2. Made
3. Give
4. No improvement.

This is my exam question and only one option is correct but I think option 2 and 4 both are correct.

Comment: Please clarify what the full wording of the question is, or what you are expected to do with these options. As it stands, there isn't actually a question here. Also please make it clear what part you are having trouble understanding - or whether you are just asking somebody to double check your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. There are two correct answers: (2) **made** and (4) **no improvement** (I guess that this mean **gave**)

You can discard (1) and (3) because being right semantically, they are not correct grammatically, verbs are not in the expected tense, that should be **delivered** and **gave**.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**speech**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speech)

> a formal talk given usually to a large number of people on a special
>   occasion:
>
> I had to **give/make** a speech at my brother's wedding.

Here you can read more about all verbs being semantically appropriated.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143469/is-give-a-speech-idiomatic-english

Comment: @Araucaria You're right. The edition made in the title confused me. [Editing]

Comment: I think this answer has missed the presumed point of the exercise and so is wrong. See my answer below. I shall not down vote because the exercise sort of invites confusion as to whether meaning or form is being tested.

Comment: I see now that the answer given above is correct. I misread. I apologize and shall delete my contrary answer.